# When is ValidationSummary loaded?

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to realize when the ValidationSummary really loads and how can I force it to be loaded.

I've suscribed to loaded event to force a page validation and this is only triggered when I cause any "new" validation or open a ComboBox or something like this.

Any idea?? Thanks in advance.

Here goes my view:

```
<Grid Margin="0,3">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<sdk:Label Grid.Column="0" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtImporteTotal}" Content="Total Acto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0"></sdk:Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtImporteTotal" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ActoMedico.importe_total, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"></TextBox>
<sdk:DescriptionViewer Target="{Binding ElementName=txtImporteTotal}" Grid.Column="2"></sdk:DescriptionViewer>
<sdk:Label Grid.Column="3" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtImporteMedico}" Content="Total Médico" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0"></sdk:Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="4" Name="txtImporteMedico" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ActoMedico.importe_medico, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"></TextBox>
<sdk:DescriptionViewer Target="{Binding ElementName=txtImporteMedico}" Grid.Column="5"></sdk:DescriptionViewer>
```

This is its code behind, where I'm forcing the validation:

```
public ActoMedico()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.validationSummary.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(validationSummary_Loaded);
}

void validationSummary_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.forzarValidacion();
    }


    private void forzarValidacion()
    {
       this.txtImporteMedico.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
        this.txtImporteTotal.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

And finally, this is the model:

```
#region importe_medico
        public const string importe_medicoPropertyName = "importe_medico";

        private double? _importe_medico;

        [Display(Description = "Importe")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar el importe")]
        public double? importe_medico
        {
            get
            {
                return _importe_medico;
            }

            set
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = importe_medicoPropertyName });

                _importe_medico = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(importe_medicoPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion

#region importe_total
        public const string importe_totalPropertyName = "importe_total";

        private double? _importe_total;
        [Display(Description = "Importe total")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar el importe total")]
        public double? importe_total
        {
            get
            {
                return _importe_total;
            }

            set
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = importe_totalPropertyName });

                _importe_total = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(importe_totalPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: It is loaded when a control triggers the BindingValidationError event. But you can generate a validation error from a view model which is bound to the view.

Comment: I want to generate that validation error but it doesn't seems to work... It should work by setting a "required" property text to "" shoudln't it?

Comment: No, not always. Add the code which doesn't work to your post, it will be much easier to answer then.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can't post it know because I'm not at work (next monday I'll can). Thanks again.

Comment: I've tested your code, in my case it displays the ValidationSummary control but with errors such as "Input string had an incorrect format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get this by forcing a combobox to drop-down, force all the form validations and then undo the drop-down.

So I get the ValidationSummary from the beginning (I want every error from the start to be shown and disable the "save" button for the user.

Thanks so much for your help @vorrtex.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you use the binding like `{Binding ActoMedico.importe_total}` in your text boxes. It means that the object bound to the `UserControl` must contain the property `ActoMedico` and the value of this property must contain the inner property `importe_total`.

I've added the following code to the code behind:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.ActoMedico = new ItemViewModel();
    }

    public ItemViewModel ActoMedico { get; set; }
}

//...
public ActoMedico()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(); //should be set in order to make bindings work
    this.validationSummary.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(validationSummary_Loaded);
}
```

In the code above the `ItemViewModel` class is the class which contains those two properties from you last block of code. This class has a different name in your application, but I don't know it so I've named it in my way.

So now the `ValidationSummary` control will be displayed but with messages like `Input string had an incorrect format`. It is because the `TextBox` control expects the `string` data type whereas your view model has the `double?` data type. You can write a converter as a workaround to this issue:

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = (string)value;
        double d;

        if (!double.TryParse(str, out d))
            return null;

        return d;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="DoubleToStringConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding ActoMedico.importe_total, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringConverter} ...
```

Anyway data annotations aren't easy to work with, so I reccomend to use the MVVM pattern and the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. I've implemented the example of such validation [here in my post](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/wpf-validation-with-idataerrorinfo/), you can download source code and look how it is implemented.

Comment: My ValidationSummary doesn't display until I force a new error :-(

Comment: @zapico It is reasonable because if there are no errors - there will be nothing to display in the ValidationSummary.

Comment: Yes but there are :-(. I just can't understand this... if I force the validation on the onLoad event of the window, the errors are shown in every control but not in the validation summary...

Comment: @zapico To display the ValidationSummary control, you should just add the `NotifyOnValidationError=True` definition to the binding and put the ValidationSummary somewhere inside one of the parent elements. That's all, if an error is displayed near a control - it should be displayed in the summary too. Anyway you can post another question on this site with detailed description of this problem.